# Bootstrap Three Vertical Input Groups

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to reproduce this below using three HTML inputs and Bootstrap 4. But I can't do it. How can I reproduce do this?

[image]

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text">
  <div>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made something like it using Plain Css:

```html
<div class="input-group" style="position:absolute;">
  <input type="text" style="width:40px;height:35px;">
  <div>
    <input type="text" style="position:absolute;top:0;width:25px;border-radius:0px 10px 0px 0px;left:43px;">
    <input type="text" style="position:absolute;left:43px;top:20px;width:25.5px;">
  </div>
</div>
```